# Unix string replacement

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to change a game's game files by using simple byte editing, but whenever I save it (I tried with all available encodings) some characters go missing.
Any tips on fixing it? (btw it only happens when I replace a string, not before)

Comment: Can you provide examples of the code you've tried and what the input and output look like?

Comment: You could provide a snapshot of a Hex Editor that shows that string composition. The code you're using to replace those bytes won't hurt the feelings of anyone.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try using a `System.IO.FileStream` and then read in the values to a byte array. You can then use the read method. Here is an example:

````
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim fs As System.IO.FileStream
        Dim fsOut As System.IO.FileStream

        Dim path As String = "[YourInputFileLocation]"
        Dim pathOut As String = "[YourOutputFileLocation]"

        Dim b() As Byte
        Dim bytEdit() As Byte = {}
        Dim bytLeft() As Byte = {}
        Dim bytRight() As Byte = {}

        Dim strTemp As String
        Dim intPos As Integer
        Dim strFind As String
        Dim lngFileSize As Long
        Dim lngFilePos As Long
        Dim intLen As Integer
        Dim strOut As String = "NoAppliance"
        Dim blnWriteData As Boolean
        Dim blnAtEnd As Boolean

        'Open the stream and read it. 
        fs = New System.IO.FileStream(path, IO.FileMode.Open)
        fsOut = New System.IO.FileStream(pathOut, IO.FileMode.Create)

        lngFileSize = 0
        lngFilePos = 0
        lngFileSize = fs.Length
        blnAtEnd = False
        Do While Not blnAtEnd ' .Read(b, 0, b.Length) > 0
            If lngFilePos + 1024 > lngFileSize Then
                ReDim b(0 To lngFileSize - lngFilePos - 1)
                blnAtEnd = True
            Else
                ReDim b(0 To 1023)
            End If
            fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length)

            blnWriteData = False

            strTemp = BytesToString(b)

            strFind = "blender"

            intPos = InStr(strTemp, strFind)
            If intPos > 0 Then
                blnWriteData = True

                intLen = Len(strFind)

                ReDim bytLeft(0 To (intPos - 1) - 1)
                ReDim bytEdit(0 To (intLen - 1))
                ReDim bytRight(0 To (b.Length - bytLeft.Count - bytEdit.Count - 1))

                Array.ConstrainedCopy(b, 0, bytLeft, 0, bytLeft.Count)
                Array.ConstrainedCopy(b, intPos - 1, bytEdit, 0, bytEdit.Count)
                Array.ConstrainedCopy(b, intPos - 1 + intLen, bytRight, 0, bytRight.Count)

                Debug.Print("Count (1024) = " & bytLeft.Count + bytEdit.Count + bytRight.Count)
                'Edit the bytes that you wish!

                ReDim bytEdit(0 To (Len(strOut) - 1))
                bytEdit = StringToBytes(strOut)
            End If

            'Finally, Write out bytes to a new FileStream
            If blnWriteData Then
                fsOut.Write(bytLeft, 0, bytLeft.Count)
                fsOut.Write(bytEdit, 0, bytEdit.Count)
                fsOut.Write(bytRight, 0, bytRight.Count)
            Else
                fsOut.Write(b, 0, b.Count)
            End If

            lngFilePos += b.Length
        Loop

        Debug.Print(fs.Length)
        Debug.Print(fsOut.Length)

        fsOut.Close()
        fs.Close()

        fsOut = Nothing
        fs = Nothing
    End Sub

    Private Function StringToBytes(strInString As String) As Byte()
        Dim bytOut() As Byte
        Dim intI As Integer
        Dim intLen As Integer
        Dim chrIn() As Char
        Dim bytTemp() As Byte

        chrIn = strInString.ToCharArray

        intLen = Len(strInString)
        ReDim bytOut(0 To intLen - 1)
        For intI = 0 To (intLen - 1)
            bytTemp = BitConverter.GetBytes(chrIn(intI))    'CByte(AscW(Mid(strInString, intI, 1)))
            Array.ConstrainedCopy(bytTemp, 0, bytOut, intI, 1)
        Next intI

        Return bytOut
    End Function

    Private Function BytesToString(bytIn() As Byte) As String
        Dim strOut As String
        Dim intI As Integer

        strOut = ""
        For intI = 0 To UBound(bytIn)
            strOut = strOut & ChrW(bytIn(intI))
        Next intI

        Return strOut
    End Function```
````